# Spring REST - Can a RestTemplate consume multipart/mixed?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate, multipartform-data

I want to write a REST service which does responed with a zipFile and some json data, everything in one multipart/mixed request.

The server part works fine and i am testing it with the REST Client from firefox. My Server sends a multipart like this

```
--k-dXaXvCFusLVXUsg-ryiHMmkdttadgcBqi4XH

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form"
Content-type: application/json

{"projectName":"test","signal":"true"}

--k-dXaXvCFusLVXUsg-ryiHMmkdttadgcBqi4XH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file2"; filename="file2.txt"
Content-type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 10

hallo=Welt
```

I know that RestTemplate can send multiparts with the help of a MultiValueMap out of the box.

Now I tried to consume multipart/mixed responses and return a MultiValueMap

```
@Component
public class RestCommand 
extends AbstractLoginRestCommand<Form, MultiValueMap<String, Object>>
{
    @Override
    protected MultiValueMap<String, Object> executeInternal ( Form form )
    {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate();
        MyMultiValueMap map = restTemplate.postForObject(getUrl(), form, MyMultiValueMap.class);
        return new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>(map);
    }
}

class MyMultiValueMap extends LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>
{}
```

MyMultiValueMap exist to prevent type erasure (generics).

This gives

> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract
>   response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type
>   [class org.jlot.client.remote.MyMultiValueMap] and content type
>   [multipart/form-data;boundary=Rjh-fkdsI9OIyPpYwdFY7lsUIewhRSX8kE19I;charset=UTF-8]
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:492)

Javadoc of FormHttpMessageConverter says it can write but not read multipart/form-data.

Why is it like this?

Is there a way to read multipart/form-data with RestTemplate out-of-the-box or do I need to write a HttpMessageConverter?

Comment: Did you got answer to your problem? Below answer not working for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I think I achieved what you wanted.
You just have to override the `canRead` method of the form converter. With your example something like below should work.

```
FormHttpMessageConverter formConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter() {
    @Override
    public boolean canRead(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        if (clazz == MyMultiValueMap.class) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.canRead(clazz, mediaType);
    }
};
```

And add this converter to your rest template.

Comment: I have used this approach, but MyMultiValueMap does not properly separate application/octet-stream and application/json? How can we separate this two properly? As per following link(http://mfjassociates.blogspot.in/2012/02/handling-multipart-form-data-in-spring.html) multipart/mixed is not supported properly? Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution at the moment:

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping(value = JlotApiUrls.PUSH, produces = "application/json")
public List<PushResultDTO> push ( 
        @PathVariable String projectName,       
        @PathVariable String versionName, 
        @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile multipartFile, 
        @RequestPart("data") @Valid PushForm pushForm 
   ) throws IOException, BindException
{
 ...
}
```

https://github.com/kicktipp/jlot/blob/master/jlot-web/src/main/java/org/jlot/web/api/controller/PushController.java