# Handle multipart/mixed response with Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, multipart, resttemplate

I'm making a rest call to an endpoint that returns a multipart/mixed payload.

Here's the call using Spring's RestTemplate:

```
ResponseEntity<String> res = template.exchange(queryStr, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

I know I can get the entire body from the ResponseEntity as a String, but I don't want to have to manually parse it. Isn't there a more elegant way to handle the **parsing** of multipart/mixed. I've tried things like:

```
ResponseEntity<MultipartFile> res = template.exchange(queryStr, HttpMethod.GET, entity, MultipartFile.class);
```

but I get this exception:

> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [interface org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile] and content type [multipart/mixed;boundary=ML_BOUNDARY_10842596526049964806]

Thoughts?

Comment: Do You mean that the response can contain many different types of payload, depending on something?
If so, the only option that I see at the moment is to implement Objects representing all of possible response types, and then when You get Your JSON String from ResponseEntity, You can try to use ObjectMapper for mapping this JSON to all of the possible responses. You simply catch the mapping error and try with another type. 

But I guess that this is the "manual parsing" that You're trying to avoid?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918459/spring-rest-can-a-resttemplate-consume-multipart-mixed ?

Comment: multipart/mixed has a certain kind of structure, although its parts can be different. I'd like to find any easy way to parse the overall structure (like with MultipartFile) and then handle the parts manually.

Comment: @Nicholas That solution just puts the response in a map where the value is the entire body.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to write your own HttpMessageConverter to handle "application/octet" types?