# Spring RestTemplate message converter to read/consume mulitpart/mixed response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, resttemplate, multipart

Spring does provide a message converter which can **write** multipart responses out of the box:
[FormHttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.html), according to its javadoc:

> In other words, this converter can read and write the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" media type as MultiValueMap, and it can also write (**but not read**) the "multipart/form-data" and "multipart/mixed" media types as MultiValueMap.

However, there is no known out-of-the box converter to **read** such a response. There is a codec though which is able to read multipart/form-data but not multipart/mixed: [MultipartHttpMessageReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/multipart/https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/multipart/MultipartHttpMessageReader.html)

There is also a similar converter in the spring-integration which is able to read multipart/form-data: [MultipartAwareFormHttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/integration/http/converter/MultipartAwareFormHttpMessageConverter.html)

The questions are:

1. Why spring doesn't include this functionality into out-of-the box converter?
2. What is the easiest and proper way to read/consume multipart/mixed response context?

I have found a very similar question but the asnwer is not accepted, so I am not sure if mentioned way is a recommended approach: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918459/spring-rest-can-a-resttemplate-consume-multipart-mixed)